# linux - headphones and speaker works only AFTER resume from sleep

Tags: linux, ubuntu, audio, linux-mint, alsa

Good day all

For quite some time I have had this issue, not distro specific, I assume it is a kernel related issue.

```
aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: VT1802 Analog [VT1802 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 2: VT1802 Alt Analog [VT1802 Alt Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: Headset [Logitech G930 Headset], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0


lspci -v | grep Audio
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
```

My USB Logitech headset always functions, no matter cold or hot boot, and I recently got this, so the USB headset is not the issue.

All sound configurations were left stock, except of course for volume changes

This occured since I started using Linux with Linux Mint 14, with Mint 15, Ubuntu 15.04 and Ubuntu 15.10, I am not sure about others since I haven't used them

For some reason, either my card is not properly detected/configured on a cold boot but runs this script/procedure when resuming

Answer (score 0):

On my desktop with Linux Mint 17.3 I also had a problem with sound that would only work after resuming from suspend. That has proved not to be consistent way to make sound work. I tried lately to unplug replug the phono plug to the computer and on the other end the phono plug to the speaker. That somehow made my sound work again. The plugs were not lose or improperly plugged.